# Fake javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, upload

I'm trying to upload a few thousand of PNG images to a site (powered by ASP.NET) using a C# bot.

They're using the following button to submit the upload on their site.

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphRoblox$UploadButton" 
    value="Create Shirt" 
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
    new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cphRoblox$UploadButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" 
    id="ctl00_cphRoblox_UploadButton" class="translate" 
/>
```

Now, the problem I didn't manage to find a solution for is: How can I fake such a behavior with C#?

Comment: Why not ask them if they have an API you could leverage.

Comment: They don't have an API, nor are they willing to spend time on adding one.

Comment: You are effectively writing a web client in C# that can submit a form without needing to receive the HTML for said form. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813338/submit-web-form-and-get-response-data-in-c-sharp